# Emulating CMD to run a directory dependent game on a webpage?

Tags: html, user-interface, embed, online-storage

I've been developing a text adventure in python that runs in the windows command prompt. I didn't think to host this online until it was done, so i'm hoping there's a way to emulate CMD and run the game in a web browser, but this may be difficult due to the nature of how the game functions.

Basically, everything from items to enemies to events are stored in plain text files, allowing for users to create their own stories and whatnot through a dev console in game. When certain triggers happen, these files are modified. For example, unlocking a door changes a line in the specific area file. So it's crucial that the user have their own sandbox of the original directory, otherwise events wouldn't work and the game wouldn't function.

I've seen a similar set up to run old DOS games online but due to the sandbox directory aspect, I wouldn't be surprised if this was effectively impossible. I'm hoping you guys have some idea of how I could go about this without rewriting the source entirely. ]]